# Angular routes - ignore unmatched paths

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

Angular's ngRoute intercepts paths for which it has no match. Is there a way to turn this off? Some sort of `.otherwise('business as usual')` that I'm missing?

I'm using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`, which is intentional.

`ui-router` does not do this by default. There is an `.else(...)` option, but if you don't call it, `ui-router` lets the browser handle unmatched urls as usual. This is the behavior I want; just, for `ngRoute`.

Example: http://chbrown.github.io/sandbox/javascript/angular/routing.html

- The first two links on that page work as expected.
- The third link ("Elsewhere") should 404 (as it does if you click on it and then submit the url in your browser or refresh manually).

I think `ui-router` is the "right" solution in this case, but is there any way to get `ngRoute` to play nice with non-ngRoute site (local) urls?

Answer (score 1):

I've pretty much settled that `ui-router` has effectively superseded `ngRoute` (no compelling case for `ngRoute` given that there is `ui-router`), so here's the way I'm currently handling out-of-scope links when using `ui-router`:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function(injector, location) {
    // N.b.: arguments are not injected via usual Angular magic, thus no $'s;
    //     the second argument, location, is not the same as window.location

    // In my case, I want any urls that DON'T start with /admin to escape
    //     ui-router's control
    var path = location.path();
    if (!path.match(/^\/admin/)) {
      window.location = path;
    }
    // else: could redirect to some default /admin homepage or something
  });

  $stateProvider.state(...).state(...); // etc.

});
```

With `.html5Mode(true)`, it makes sense that the library is going to catch *every* url change. I wish I didn't have to use `window.location`—that I could return `false` from `.otherwise()` in order to signal that I don't want `ui-router` to handle the request—but I expect that even if that were the case, `ui-router` would do the same thing under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve this is to disallow link rewrites.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false,
  rewriteLinks: false
});
```

Normally Angular intercepts each url and rewrites them but by setting the `rewriteLinks` option to `false`, you can bypass this behaviour.